# Column child Container covers full width of parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am adding a Container inside Column. I have given Container fixed width 60% of device width and height is 30% of device height. For height it is reflecting good but width covering whole parent.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.30,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.20,
              height: 40,
              child: Text('test'),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: chatList.map((chatModel) {
                return ChatTileWidget(chatModel: chatModel,);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: @pskink not useful for me.

Comment: @CodeHunter it seems you forgot to multiply 0.60 on container width.

Comment: Check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints to understand how constraints works @CodeHunter

Comment: Hey @CodeHunter, I have answered your question. Let me know if that helped you. Would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Constraints in `Flutter` works different than usual. If you want to give `height` and `width` to the child, it will usually follows its parents constraints.

To read more about `Constraints` in `Flutter`: [Understanding Constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints).

To get what you want, you need to use `Align` and set the `alignment` property to your preferred position. Here is an example for you. I have wrapped your inner `Container` with an `Align` widget and set the `alignment` to `topLeft` so it doesn't take it's parent `height` and `width`:

```
     Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                child: Text('test')
              )
            )
          )
        ]
      )
```

**RESULT**

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE]

To know more about `Align`, please see this: [Align Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html).